# Property "$scopedSlots" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance - when trying to use VueSlickCarousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I am currently learning to work with Vue.js and I am trying to set up a quick carousel using this library I found: https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/

When I try to render the component I keep getting this error **Property "$scopedSlots" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance**.

I have tried tweaking my code but nothing seems to be working. Here is my current code:

I set up my app.js like this

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';

const app = createApp({});

import VueSlickCarouselComponent from './components/VueSlickCarouselComponent.vue'
app.component('vue-slick-carousel-component', VueSlickCarouselComponent);
app.mount('#carousel');
```

Then I set up my VueSlickCarouselComponent.vue like this copied directly from the documentation page. This is my component to load the carousel.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <VueSlickCarousel>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
        </VueSlickCarousel>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
// optional style for arrows & dots
import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css'

export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    components: { VueSlickCarousel },
}
</script>
```

And finally my blade file loading the component looks like this

```
<div id="carousel">
    <vue-slick-carousel-component></vue-slick-carousel-component>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me understand what the issue means and what am I doing wrong?

I tried following the ExampleComponent setup of Vue itself and can show static data through my custom component, however as soon as I add the library's component I get the error.

I have tried other libraries as well and all of them return the same error, so I must be loading something wrong. However nothing on the internet has been helpful in solving this issue so far.

Comment: It's a shame the documentation makes no mention of it, but the library [does not support Vue 3](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/issues/238).  It is an older library that will only work with Vue 2.  You will need to find a different carousel library that supports Vue 3.

Comment: Thanks for this! I did a google search based on this info and confirmed it's not Vue 3 compatible and found and alternative I will try out. Is Vue 3 a relatively new library if most first page google search results don't work with it?